# Is the following fragment of Java correct?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Is the following fragment of Java correct?  In the positive case, the method `fie` is redefined (overridden)? What does it print?

```
class A {
    int x = 4;
    int fie (A p) { return p.x;}
}

class B extends A {
    int y = 6;
    int fie (B p) { return p.x + p.y;}
}

B b = new B();
A a = new A();
int zz = a.fie(a) +b.fie(a);  //here,b.fie(a)---how is this working?
System.out.println(zz);
```

Please help me to answer this question. I'm working on OOP Inheritance but I still don't understand why `b.fie(a)` is ok. I've tested it on Eclipse and it worked properly. It prints out 14. I guess there is no overridden here. But how can the method `fie(B p) {...}` in Class B access `p.y` while the parameter passed in is `ac` (type A)?

Comment: B extends A and has both int fie (A p) and fie (B p). So polymorphism is causing this to work. You are not actually overriding fie(A a), which I assume you were intending.

Comment: This code prints 8, not 14. If it prints 14, you're not running the code that you have posted. `b.fie(a)` calls `int fie (A p)` in class A, which class B has inherited.

Comment: i wonder why it would print 14,it would print 8.Also Class B method are not overriding class A method

Answer (score 0):

The method is not overriden as the two methods have different parameters. The method fie is therefore overloaded.

`b.fie(a)` will call the method defined in class `A`
`a.fie(b)` will also call the method defined in class `A`
`b.fie(b)` will call the method defined in class `B`, now y is accessed.

```
A c = new B();
c.fie(b);
```

will also call the method defined in class `A` (this is because fie is overloaded and not overridden!)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the third case. Why c.fie(b) will call method defined in class A instead of the one in class B. c point to a instance object of class B. Moreover, the parameter passed in is type B.

Comment: fie in class A and B are completely different methods. They just share the same name (that's overloading). B does NOT override fie of A.

Answer (score 0):

In class B you don't override the fie method, but overloading it. It's using a different methods signature. So class B has 2 fie methods. One that accept class A and one that accepts class B.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to print 8, not 14.

B extends A, and inherits int fie (A p).
Also, B defines int fie (B p)

These two methods does NOT collide as they are different methods. Both have the same name, but different signature (one accepts A and the other B as parameters). This is a example of method overloading NOT overriding.

So, when you invoke b.fie(a), as a is of type A, it calls the method inherited from A (B has another method with same name, but it is a different method, as the signature is different).

So, a.fie(a) +b.fie(a) will invoke twice the method defined by A, and it will add 4 + 4.